I work with dictionaries in Python and constantly face such a problem: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" What to do?
>>> d = {'year':[{'season':['winter',['spring']]}]}
>>> d['year']['season']['winter']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<python-input-2>", line 2, in <module>
    d['year']['season']['winter']
    ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I tried to change the names of the variables, but it didn't do anything. What do I need to do to "pull out" the "spring"?

What do you think d['year']['season']['winter'] should be?

The value of the key year is a list, so you need to index the list.  Just go step-by-step to figure it out:
>>> d = {'year':[{'season':['winter',['spring']]}]}
>>> d['year']  # result is list
[{'season': ['winter', ['spring']]}]
>>> d['year'][0]  # result is dict
{'season': ['winter', ['spring']]}
>>> d['year'][0]['season']  # result is list
['winter', ['spring']]
>>> d['year'][0]['season'][1]  # result is another list
['spring']
>>> d['year'][0]['season'][1][0]  # result is string
'spring'

